# SQL Server Login attempts fail when using SSMS but succeed when using SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have my SQLServer 2005 instance configured for mixed mode fine. When using SSMS, none of the sql server logins seem to work. Just "Login failed for user '..'" message. But when I use SQLCMD, it works fine. The behavior is not just for one specific login account. All sql server logins including 'sa' fail when tried via SSMS. Windows logins work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue seems to be with the local SSMS install on the server. Everything works fine from odbc connections, remote SSMS connections etc.

Comment: If it is local, try forcing SSMS to use TCP instead of Shared Memory. You could also check to make sure someone didn't disable that protocol on the server.